# Is there a Jacobi–Trudi formula for skew zonal polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions

Skew Schur polynomials are defined as $s_{\lambda/\mu}=\sum_\nu c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}s_\nu$, where the Littlewood–Richardson coefficients $c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ satisfy $s_\mu(x)s_\nu(x)=\sum_\lambda c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}s_\lambda(x)$.

However, it is possible to compute the skew Schur polynomials without knowing the Littlewood–Richardson coefficients, because there is a formula expressing them as a determinant, the Jacobi–Trudi formula.

LIkewise, skew zonal polynomials are defined as $Z_{\lambda/\mu}=\sum_\nu b^\lambda_{\mu\nu}Z_\nu$, where the coefficients $b^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ satisfy $Z_\mu(x)Z_\nu(x)=\sum_\lambda b^\lambda_{\mu\nu}Z_\lambda(x)$.

Is it possible to compute the skew zonal polynomials without knowing the $b$ coefficients, using some analogue of the Jacobi–Trudi formula? I am actually only interested in the simplest quantity $Z_{\lambda/\mu}(1^N)$.

([Is there a formula for skew Macdonald functions similar to Jacobi-Trudi identity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256434/is-there-a-formula-for-skew-macdonald-functions-similar-to-jacobi-trudi-identity) is a similar question about Macdonald polynomials. Zonal polynomials are a very particular case for which a lot more is known.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything about Jacobi–Trudi for skew zonal polynomials.

For usual zonal polynomials, Kerov has shown ([*Generalized Hall–Littlewood symmetric functions and orthogonal polynomials*](http://www.ams.org/books/advsov/009/)) that, when $\lambda=(r,1^s)$ is a hook, then $Z_{\lambda'}$ can be written as a determinant,
$$ Z_{\lambda'}\propto\det\left(\frac{\lambda_i+2s-i-j+2}{\lambda_i+2s-2i+2}e_{\lambda_i-i+j}\right). $$

On the other hand, Matsumoto has shown ([*Two parameters circular ensembles and Jacobi–Trudi type formulas for Jack functions of rectangular shapes*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608751v1)) that, when $\lambda=(r^\ell)$ is of rectangular shape, then $Z_{\lambda'}$ can be written as a pfaffian,
$$ Z_{\lambda'}\propto\operatorname{Pf}\left((j-i)e_{r+2\ell-i-j+1}\right). $$

These results are particular cases of a theorem of Lassalle and Schlosser ([*Inversion of the Pieri formula for Macdonald polynomials*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2005.03.009)) which gives a recurrence relation for generic zonal polynomials. This seems to be the state of the art in terms of Jacobi–Trudi-like formulas.

It is not clear to me under what circumstances these recurrence relations can be cast in the form of a determinant or a pfaffian. It is also not clear whether something similar holds for skew zonal polynomials.

Comment: I added some links, but couldn't find the Matsumoto paper you mentioned.  Do you have a more detailed reference?

Comment: @LSpice here: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.236.5040&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Ah, I see; its latest version on the arXiv is called, and it was apparently published as, [Matsumoto - Moments of characteristic polynomial for compact symmetric spaces and Jack ensembles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/40/45/006).